# SSRS: Next and Previous page buttons don't work

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting

I have a vs2012 web project using NET 3.5 and the SSRS reportviewer control (v11) running on MSSQL 2008.  When the report displays the next page button doesn't work.  It appears to respond to the click (ie the button is enabled and the page load event in the code behind is called) but it doesn't display a new page.  When I access the report directly thru the SSRS reportserver URL, I get the same page but it works without any problems. Also, when I export the report to a PDF using the built in export option on the same screen, the correct, entire report is there.  I believe viewstate is enabled...no mvc.  Here is the relevant code:

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSRSUrl"]);
param[0] = new ReportParameter("SubTitle", subTitle);
param[1] = new ReportParameter("Query", query);
param[2] = new ReportParameter("Parameters", reportParameterString);               
param[3] = new ReportParameter("Title2", title2);
ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
if (!IsPostBack) ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(param);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: I always found that iframes work better than the viewer.

Comment: I am getting this as well after upgrading from ReportViewer 9 to 11 in a WebApp running against SQL 2008 R2 in ASP.Net 4.0. So far no answers. Found this article, but it has no answers either.